# Calculating average in mongo doesn't return the expected result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

I've tried the following:

```
db.load_time.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$computer_name", avgPerfo: {$avg: "$test_results.performance"}}}])
```

A document looks like this:

```
mongos> db.load_time.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d3784c1793e649b4360665"),
    "computer_name" : "machine1",
    "git_commit" : "b25ae9407e94e3cfefec8f11551f13d711da959c",
    "test_results" : [
        {
            "performance" : 75893,
            "test_function_name" : "func1"
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns null for the average. No idea why.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I am not asking how to do it, I am asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've figured out the issue. I had to unwind first the test_results before calculating the average.